# Android Floating Action Button Behaviour with Adview

Tags: android-layout

I'm sorry if this has been already answered but it's been a while and I'm still searching. Since the FAB has a behaviour class you can assign to it which will work with scrolling inside a coordinator layout, I was wondering if it was possible to include behaviour to make the FAB automatically get placed above an adview when it is visible similar to how it reacts to a snack bar. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Work Around!**

I figured out a work around as I was just playing around some time back, even forgot about the question. Instead of putting my adview inside a container with the rest of my views I simply had to wrap the coordinator view in a Relative layout and set the coordinator layout above the adview ID. I'm sure this might not be the best way to do it.

So what I ended up having is this: NB My adview is set to visibility gone by default and I only set the visibility when the adrequest is complete

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_behavior="utils.FabBehavior_Main"
        app:rippleColor="@color/fab_ripple"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The utils.FabBehavior_Main is the relative package class that contains the behaviour properties for the view, utils being the package. So in your own application you could have the name space com.myapp.utils.ScrollAwareFab which would have be like this:

```
public class ScrollAwareFab extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {

    public ScrollAwareFab(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                       FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL ||
                super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target,
                                          nestedScrollAxes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child,
                               View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed,
                             dyUnconsumed);

        if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            child.hide(new FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
                /**
                 * Called when a FloatingActionButton has been hidden
                 *
                 * @param fab the FloatingActionButton that was hidden.
                 */
                @Override
                public void onHidden(FloatingActionButton fab) {
                    super.onShown(fab);
                    fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            child.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you eloborate what is 'utils.FabBehavior_Main' here?

Comment: @KrunalKapadiya I just edited the answer including the class structure. The utils.FabBehavior_Main is the class location inside your application package. So in this case inside my app package e.g. com.myapp.app I have a package called utils which has multiple helper classes including FabBehavior_Main, see edited answer :)